# Is it possible to log powershell scripts which executed on my computer?

Tags: powershell, event-log, event-viewer

Title says it all. I already turned on logging via regedit but I want something more stable. I would like to see every commands which executed on powershell to be in my event log just like Sysmon.

Comment: "I would like to see every commands which executed on powershell to be in my event log just like Sysmon", so you wan to use [Start-Transcript](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript)?

Answer (score 2):

#### Is it possible to log PowerShell scripts which executed on my computer?

Yes.

> Windows PowerShell creates a Windows event log that is named "Windows PowerShell" to record Windows PowerShell events. You can view this log in Event Viewer or by using cmdlets that get events, such as the `Get-EventLog` cmdlet. By default, Windows PowerShell engine and provider events are recorded in the event log, but you can use the event log preference variables to customize the event log. For example, you can add events about Windows PowerShell commands.

Source [about Eventlogs - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_eventlogs?view=powershell-5.1)

> PowerShell logs details about PowerShell operations, such as starting and stopping the engine and providers, and executing PowerShell commands.

You need to register the PowerShell Event Provider:

> Run the following command from an elevated PowerShell prompt.
> PowerShell
>
> ```
> $PSHOME\RegisterManifest.ps1
> ```

And enable Script Block Logging:

> When you enable Script Block Logging, PowerShell records the content of all script blocks that it processes. Once enabled, any new PowerShell session logs this information.
>
> Run the following function:
>
> ```
> function Enable-PSScriptBlockLogging
> {
>     $basePath = 'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows' +
>       '\PowerShell\ScriptBlockLogging'
>
>     if(-not (Test-Path $basePath))
>     {
>         $null = New-Item $basePath -Force
>     }
>
>     Set-ItemProperty $basePath -Name EnableScriptBlockLogging -Value "1"
> }
> ```

Source [about Logging Windows - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logging_windows?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score 0):

David is spot on here but there are several other logging features, all can be set via GPO/LPO on your computer(s).

[Script Tracing and Logging](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/wmf/whats-new/script-logging?view=powershell-7.2)

Logging is enabled through the Turn on PowerShell Script Block Logging Group Policy setting in Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell.

[image]